# How To Rename The Extension of All The Files In A Directory Tree With Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm trying to rename the extensions of all the files in a directory and i tried using
`ren *.[old]* *.[new]`
but that only renamed files in my current directory. Does anyone know how i could rename the extensions of a folder and all of its sub-folders as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for /R /D %i in (*.*) do ren %i\*.old *.new`

The `/D` will select directories only, and the `/R` will recurse subdirectories.

Comment: Actually, this will not rename files in the root, and quotes should be used. Better to use `for /r /d %F in (.) do ren "%F\*.old" *.new`

Comment: trying to rename *.xml.imp into *.xml with this method results in files like *.xml.xml - also with dbenham 's method

Answer (score 0):

```
    @echo off

    pushd c:\directory\with\the\files\

 for /r %%a in (\) do (
  pushd  %%~fa
  ren *.old *.new 2>nul
  popd
 )
```